# Wordpress - Show different menus

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a problem programming a website for a customer. I a couple of normal pages on a wordpress installation. One page needs to be a different theme. I have used the [Multiple Themes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/) plugin for that. Now i need to display a different menu from the first site. 
Since I have multiple function.php i made a short change that grabs the wpb_custom_new_menu() function from a seperate file by require_once.
Then in the header.php where it is supposed to be shown, I have a normal wp_nav_menu(). I changed both themes to work on this system, my normal theme workes fine, but on the second one the menu isn't shown. It's not the themes fault, since both themes are basicly the same exept a couple of color changes. Don't know if anyone can help me, but I thought I'd give it a shot. 
Thanks!

Comment: do you want to show multi pal menu on different page in wordpress?

Comment: Please don't append _solved_. Instead post an answer and mark it as accepted. See [ask] and take the [tour]. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

p.s. There is no solution. It just doesn't work, it's a limitation  of how wordpress themes work. I spoke to a good friend and he suggested this plugin and it works great: 
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-different-navigation-on-each-page-and-post/

Comment: Could you update the answer and post the real solution so it can help others? Thanks

Comment: There is no solution. It just doesn't work, it's a limitation  of how wordpress themes work. I spoke to a good friend and he suggested this plugin and it works great: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-different-navigation-on-each-page-and-post/